# expand a textbox with a switch in android studio

Tags: android-studio, switch-statement, expand, minimize

Thanks for taking a second and responding to my question if you get the time; I'm fairly new to programming android.

I want to have activities in my app with a lot of text. I want to be able to minimize and expand textboxes with a switch.

I attached a image to show what i mean.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/swswu.jpg)

By the way I'm using kotlin.

I tried putting in a standard switch but i don't know how to include the function for a expanding/minimizing textbox.